# How to Delete a Managed Object When a Relationship Becomes Empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I'm currently working on my first Core Data project for the iPhone. And after experimenting a little, I have some rather fundamental questions about entity relationships in core data.

Let's say I have two Entities: Event and Location. Each of them has a name attribute. An Event can only have one Location while a Location can have multiple Events. So the relationship would look like this:

```
Event <<--> Location
```

In my project I (the user) can type in the names for the Event and its Location. Then I'm creating a new object for the Event entity based on that input. I set the Location's name by accessing the Event's relationship like this:

```
event.Location.name = someCustomString;
```

Saving does work properly. I think.

My first question is:

Does Core Data create a new object for the Location entity every time I do this - even when the same Location name has been used before (and is still stored)? OR does Core Location automatically only set the relationship to an existing Location object in that case? Because for my project it is necessary to recognize Events that took place in the same location.

This also leads me to my next question:

What about deleting an Event object? When I do this I have to check if the corresponding Location is used by multiple Events. If it is, I'll nullify the relationship but keep the Location object. If not, I have to delete the Location object as well. My current approach (based on my assumption that Locations with the same name don't get double saved) looks like this:

```
Event *event = (event *)[appManager.results.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSInteger locationEvents = 0;

    for (Event *eve in appManager.results.fetchedObjects) 
    {
        if (eve.Location.name == event.Location.name) 
        {
            locationMoments++;
        }
    }

    if (locationMoments == 1) 
    {
        [appManager.managedObjectContext deleteObject:event.Location];
    }

    [appManager.managedObjectContext deleteObject:event];
```

So at least I think that I'm checking the number of events that a certain Location object refers to. But the code feels kind of itchy ... I don't know if that's the right approach. So my final question would be:
What would be the standard procedure in my scenario? If there even is one. ;)

Thank you all in advance for your answers!!

Answer (score 0):

> Does Core Data create a new object for the Location entity every time
>   I do this

No, `event.Location.name` is a keypath that is "walking" the relationship from the `Event` instance to the `Location` instance and then accessing the attribute `name`. A keypath only works for an existing object.

However, since you have one `Location` object shared with many `Event` objects, changing the `Location.name` value with any one `Event` object changes the value for all `Event` objects that share that `Location` object.

If you want a managed object to delete itself immediately when a relationship becomes empty, then put the delete code in the `remove…` accessor methods for the class. When the relationship hits zero, have the object tell the context to delete it. That lets you put the code in just one place instead of spread out everywhere you might change the relationship.

If you want to only delete the object when the context is saved, put the code in the class' `willSave` method. That will trigger a deletion when the context is next saved.

Comment: You say that a keypath only works for existing objects. But when I create an Event and use the event's location name for the first time - a new Location object has to be created, hasn't it? And from that moment on, Events with that same Location.name share it automatically? Just asking. I really want to know what's going on under the hood. :) Your approach of deleting the Location objects on empty relationships sounds right. I have to look into that! Would my code sample qualify for that? Or how do you normally check for existing relations in such a context? Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: Creating an `Event` object doesn't automatically create a `Location` object, it just creates an empty `Event.location` property in the `Event` object. You have to assign either a new or existing `Location` object to the relationship. To check for a empty relationship just count the number of objects e.g. `[self.location count]==0`

Comment: Ok I get that now. And now I also realize that the problem is the way I'm saving my entities. Right now I'm creating a new Location object every time a new Event object is created. (Thought Core Data might check for duplicates automatically.) While instead I should check for an existing Location object that may contain the same name as the currently entered one. And then I just link that to my new Event. I'd have to create a fetch request for Location objects with some predicate for that purpose, right?  ... And thanks again for your help, TechZen!

Comment: In Core Data only thing guaranteed to be unique in the managed objects themselves. Each object is uniquely identified only by a managedObjectID which is a UUID. You can have an arbitrary number of managed objects that all have exactly the same attributes (although their relationships are unique because the related objects are unique.) You do need to perform a fetch or cache the existing `Location` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you very much for your help TechZen. Now I think I understand Core Data a little better. And I also got my Data Model working. Turns out that when I created my entities and the appropriate Subclasses I forgot to set the entity's classes to the created files in the Inspector. (Thought that would be set automatically - since the files were created automatically, too.) So the willSave method of my Location entities was never called. I fixed that and sorted out how to handle the relationships the right way. As I said I used a fetch request with a simple "name == %@" predicate to find previously used location names. ;)

But after all I'm using actual location data, too (Latitude, Longitude). And the coordinates of a Location will be slightly different, even if the Location and its name are the same. So I have to find a way to compare stored coordinates with the ones from the current user location. When the user is near a previously used location and uses that one's name, too - then the new coordinate data should override the old - OR it should just be left alone and the new Event gets assigned with the old Location. If you have any ideas on that, I'd be grateful, too! But I think I know what to do - mostly. :)